# How to list IP of Azure VM or HDI cluster after deployment using ARM template in the output

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-hdinsight, azure-rm-template

I have created ARM template to deploy Azure VM and HDI cluster. I want to get and list the Public IP of Azure VM and Private IP of HDI cluster headnode after deployment is finished.

Is there a way to get it using ARM template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get it using ARM template?

Based on my knowledge, you could not get VM IP with template.You could use `azure cli` to get your VM IP instead of template. If your cli on Linux, you could  use the following command after you create your VM.

```
azure vm show -g shui123 -n shui|grep "Public IP address"| awk -F: '{print $3}'
```

> I want to get and list the Public IP of Azure VM and Private IP of HDI
>   cluster headnode after deployment is finished.

Public IP of Azure VM do you mean?  Just VM or VM in HDI cluster?

If it is just a VM, you could use the command above, if it is VM in HDI cluster, Azure HDInsight cluster will not allow any public IP to be assigned to it. if you need a IP to be allocated to HDInsight cluster, you would have to create HDInsight in a VNET. the following article does talk about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-extend-hadoop-virtual-network).

You could get HDI cluster IP with ​Ambari ​RE​ST ​AP​I.

```
for HOSTNAME in $(curl -u admin:$PASSWORD -sS -G "https://shuitest.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/shuitest/hosts" | jq -r '.items[].Hosts.host_name')
do
    IP=$(curl -u admin:$PASSWORD -sS -G "https://$CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTERNAME/hosts/$HOSTNAME" | jq -r '.Hosts.ip')
  echo "$HOSTNAME <--> $IP"
done
```

More information about Ambari ​RE​ST ​AP​I please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-manage-ambari-rest-api).

Update:

If you only want to list active node IP, you could use the following commands.

```
PASSWORD=
CLUSTERNAME=

curl -u admin:$PASSWORD -sS -G "https://$CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTERNAME/services/HDFS/components/NAMENODE" |grep LiveNode>test.txt

cat test.txt |awk -F'\' '{print $2}'|sed 's/\"//g'|tail -1|awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

Comment: You could use grep "^hn" to list head node private IP

Comment: I am able to get VM IP using the first command. Where I have to use grep "hn" to head node private IP ?

Comment: You could modify the script `echo "$HOSTNAME <--> $IP" >test.txt` `cat  test.txt| grep "^hn"`

Comment: @karan Do you mean you only want to list a VM private IP? If the VM in HDI, you could not get the IP with azure cli, you need use API.

Comment: @karan If it is just a VM, you could use azure cli list private IP.

Comment: Now I am get head node IP. Is there way to active Head Node Private IP.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Could you try `curl -u admin:$password -sS -G "https://shuitest.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/shuitest/hosts"|grep "host_name"` , replace your password and cluster

Comment: Only only head node active at a time in HDI cluster. How to get active head node IP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139925/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-karan).

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is good with respect to the question asked. But, ideally you should not use the Private IP of HDI cluster headnode. This is because the private IP will change in case the head node (VM over which it is running) goes down. There is a concept of FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) of the head nodes, something like: `hn0-van.0owcbllr5hze3hxdja3mqlrhhe.ex.internal.cloudapp.net` and `hn1-van.0owcbllr5hze3hxdja3mqlrhhe.ex.internal.cloudapp.net`. Use these FQDN in place of IP address everywhere. Their DNS resolution is automatically handled by Azure vnet default DNS resolver. So no worries there.

Get FQDN:
`az network nic list --resource-group <RESOURCEGROUP>`

Replace the  with your resource group name. Check the FQDN setting of the headnode.

Once I get time, I will post the PowerShell script as well to get the exact FQDN for directly the head node.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-plan-virtual-network-deployment#multinet